# Finding elements by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

Please help me I am trying to select a picture which is a link (a trainer on a website)

This is my code:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("a[title=\"ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date\"]")
```

This is the inspect element code

```
img src="https://secure-images.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/CI9367_301_A_PREM?$SNKRS_COVER_WD$&amp;align=0,1" alt="ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date" title="ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date" class="image-component mod-image-component u-full-width" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 1s ease 0s;"
```

And this is the error im getting:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"a[title="ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date"]"}

I'm using Pycharm

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<img>` (not `<a>`) is not the root of the html, so you need to use `//img` in the xpath. You also need to add `@` before the `title`

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title=\"ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date\"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to error, Selenium unable to locate the element.
Go to the inspect element.
Locate the image you want. 
Right click on the element and go to Copy->copy Xpath.
Use that xpath.

Answer (score 0):

U are dealing with an `<img>` element not an `<a>` hyperlink element.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close. However, as the desired element is an `<img>` node instead of using `a` you need to use **`//img`** and you are using using [path](/questions/tagged/path) you need to add a `@` before the attribute name, so your working line of code will be:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title=\"ACG Air Moc 3.0 'Cargo Khaki/Oil Green' Release Date\"]")
```

However, a better approach would have been to use multiple attributes as follows:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='image-component mod-image-component u-full-width' and contains(@title, 'Cargo Khaki')][starts-with(@alt, 'ACG Air Moc 3') and contains(@title, 'Oil Green')]")
```

Comment: how comes the second one is better

Comment: @SamuelOkasia In the second xpath we have tried to avoid the complexity of handling the `'` and `/`